# echo displays the contents of the variable, and kdialog (KDE) returns an empty result

Tags: bash, kdialog

I have the following code in Bash:

```
MESSAGE () {
    VAR="$1"
    BLUE="$( tput setaf 4 )"
    RESET="$( tput sgr0 )"
    VAR="${VAR//\[ i \] /${BLUE}'[ i ] '${RESET}}"
    VAR="${VAR//#BLUE /${BLUE}}"
    VAR="${VAR//#RESET /${RESET}}"
    VAR_POPUP="$VAR"
    VAR=$( echo "$VAR" | sed 's/#POPUP //' )

    echo -e "${VAR}${RESET}"

    if ( echo "$VAR_POPUP" | grep -q -E '^#POPUP' )
    then
        VAR_POPUP="$( echo "$VAR_POPUP" | sed 's/#POPUP //' )"
        VAR_POPUP="$( echo "$VAR_POPUP" | sed 's/\[ .* \] //' )"
        echo "$VAR_POPUP" # Displaying the text of the $VAR_POPUP variable
        kdialog --passivepopup "$VAR_POPUP" # Not displaying the text of the $VAR_POPUP variable
    fi
}

MESSAGE "#POPUP [ i ] text"
```

I don't understand why the "$VAR_POPUP" variable displays nothing in connection with [kdialog](https://develop.kde.org/docs/administration/kdialog/).
The line above (echo "$VAR_POPUP") displays its value, and (kdialog --passivepopup "$VAR_POPUP") returns an empty result.

Comment: Run the script in debug mode: `bash -x script.sh`

Comment: does `kdialog --passivepopup "My Test String"` work? As above, see what the shell is processing with `set -x` (or `bash -x script`). Good luck.

Comment: As an aside, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization

Comment: Double check that `$VAR_POPUP` does not contain characters with an encoding the the terminal can display but `kdialog` can't. On it face, `kdialog --passivepopup "$VAR_POPUP"` will display the contents of `"$VAR_POPUP"` until the user clicks on it, or if you add a `<timeout>` (in seconds) after `"$VAR_POPUP"` for that many seconds. It has worked that way since at least KDE3.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the text of `$VAR_POPUP`?